# Could not find file 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip'

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, deployment

I am deploying our .NET solution on AWS cloud. The chosen service is Elastic Beanstalk -> Windows Server/IIS. The package cannot be deployed due to the error below. It contains folders with .dll files and a web.config (XML). I have never met such problems with Azure. Has somebody met such a problem with the deployment?

```
019-09-23 08:57:42,619 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Reading configuration from c:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\config\containerconfiguration
2019-09-23 08:57:42,759 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Exception during deployment.
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedException: Object of type 'package' and path 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' cannot be created.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The Zip package 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' could not be loaded. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip'.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileStreamEx.CreateInstance(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare, Nullable`1 fileLength)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipFile.Load()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String path)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 106
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 56
2019-09-23 08:57:42,775 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Unexpected Exception: System.Exception: Exception during deployment. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedException: Object of type 'package' and path 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' cannot be created.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The Zip package 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' could not be loaded. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip'.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileStreamEx.CreateInstance(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare, Nullable`1 fileLength)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipFile.Load()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String path)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 106
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 56
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in C:\code\EBDPT-IISCore\src\EBDPT-IISCore\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 71
2019-09-23 08:57:42,775 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Deployment failed: Unexpected Exception
2019-09-23 08:57:42,775 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [INFO]: Started Application Update
2019-09-23 08:57:42,775 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [ERROR]: Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

I encourage the same problem.
For dealing with that such issue, I recommend connecting to the Windows instance using RDP and try to run the 01deploy script manually using PowerShell editor. (This script is located at C:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\hooks\appdeploy\enact).

You should see any detailed error information in the output panel. In my case, the error was

> Could not find file 'C:\staging\manifest.xml'.

This could be a bit confusing because the source folder in C:/staging not contains any Manifest.xml file. However, I found that manually deploying the app using **eb deploy** command will not work and missing the required files (parameters.xml and so on). You should deploy **only using the AWSToolkitPackage**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to deploy using AWS Toolkit and then download and compare version from AWS with version that you are trying to upload. Check folder structure and content.

We had a similar issue. At first, we were deploying our application to Elastic Beanstalk using AWS Toolkit for VS, and everything worked fine. But when we tried to deploy using CodePipeline we got an error  *"Could not find file 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip'"* in the log file.

Build stage produced .zip file and everything seems to be there.  We tried to Upload and deploy that .zip file using AWS console but we got the same error.

Then we compared the content of .zip file that CodePipeline produced with .zip file from previously successfully uploaded version on Elastic Beanstalk and we realized that we are missing few folders and dlls.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but in case someone has the same problem. Make sure the MSBuild command in the pipeline has the right params, as recommended by [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/developer/deploying-net-web-applications-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-visual-studio-team-services/):

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"
```